# Show that a non invertible matrix $B$ cannot exist for $||A\vec x - B\vec x || \le 1$

Tags: linear-algebra, svd

Let $A$ be a $5\times 5$ matrix with singular values $10,10^2,10^3,10^4,10^5$. Show that there cannot exist a non-invertible matrix $B$ such that $||A\vec x - B\vec x|| \le $1 with $||\vec x|| = 4$.

My attempt:

Assume that such a matrix does exist. Then $B$ has rank $\le 5$. We know that the following holds:

$$
||A-A_k|| \le ||A-B||
$$

Where $A_k = U\Sigma_k V^T$ with $\Sigma_k$ having the $k$ largest singular values of $A$. This means that $||A_k||$ can be at most $10^4$ (using the operator norm which gives the largest singular value).

$$\begin{aligned}
||A\vec x - A_k\vec x|| &\le ||A\vec x - B\vec x|| \le 1 \newline ||A\vec x - A_k\vec x|| &= ||(A-A_k)\vec x|| \le ||A-A_k|| \cdot ||\vec x|| = 10^4 \cdot 4
\end{aligned}
$$

So basically I get that $||A\vec x - A_k\vec x||$ is less than or equal to $1$ and $4 \cdot 10^4$, however I would ideally want to show that there is a contradiction somewhere, and this is not a contradiction.

Answer (score 1):

If $B$ is singular then $Bx = 0$ for some $x$ with $\|x\|= 4$.
Then $\|Ax-Bx\| = \|Ax\| \ge \sigma_\min (A) \|x\| = 40$.

Comment: Why is $\|A\vec x\| \ge \sigma_{\text{min}}(A)\|\vec x\|$? I know that $\|A\vec x\| \le \|A\| \|\vec x\| = \sigma_{\text{max}}(A)\|\vec x\|$

Comment: One way to see this is to note that, by one definition, the singular values are the (square roots of) eigenvalues of the positive semidefinite matrix $A^*A$.